# Mensaje de error mostrado en un div desde javascript desaparece instantaneamente

Tags: javascript, bootstrap

He empezado a aprender javascript y me he topado con un error que no he podido solucionar. En el formulario que estoy desarrollando, agregue un div que tiene la clase msj-error; y al validar los campos intento cargar un mensaje con innerHTML el cual aparece y en cuestión de un instante desaparece..

Cabe recalcar que intento dejarlo por mas tiempo con setTimeOut, alguna sugerencia de como solucionar esto

```
    <div id="msj-error">
       <p>Mensaje de error de prueba</p>
    </div>
```

Anexo tambien la funcion de javascript:

```
const mostrarError=(elemento, mensaje)=>{

    divError = document.getElementById(elemento).innerHTML = `<p>${mensaje}</p>`;
    setTimeout(()=>{ divError.innerHTML = ``;},7000);

}
```

Comment: Anexaste tu código, y es posible reproducir tu error, pero por favor, adjunta tu error para futuras preguntas y descríbelo en tu planteamiento. También pásate por [¿Cómo elaboro una buena pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) y has tu [recorrido de bienvenida](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour).

Answer (score 1):

Tienes varios errores:

1. Nunca llamaste a la función ni le pasaste ningún parámetros.
2. Tienes una triple asignación que no está permitida en javascript.
3. El navegador no sabe quien es `divError` debido a la triple asignación, y eso es lo que te produce el error.

Te adjunto tu código arreglado y con un ejemplo funcional;

```js
const mostrarError=(elementoId, mensaje)=>{
    let divError = document.getElementById(elementoId)
    divError.innerHTML = `<p>${mensaje}</p>`;
    setTimeout(()=>{ divError.innerHTML = ``;},1000);
}

mostrarError('msj-error', 'Mensaje de error de prueba')
```

```html
 <div id="msj-error" class="alert alert-warning"></div>
```